# Meet an ValueError: Shapes (None, 2204) and (None, 5) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

I meet a problem when I use the tensorflow ResNet50. I create 2204 classes. And I want to train it.
but it report me the error "ValueError: Shapes (None, 2204) and (None, 5) are incompatible", does any one know where I am wrong?
I also change the classes from 5 to 2204 "pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, input_shape=(100,100,3), pooling='avg',  classes = 2204,  weights = 'imagenet')"

thank you in advanced.
the detail code looks like this:
"""

```
data_dir = r"/root/data_Camera/referenceEB"
type(data_dir)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
img_height, img_width = 100,100
batch_size = 32
trains_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split = 0.2,
  subset = "training",
  seed = 42,
  label_mode = 'categorical',
  image_size = (img_height, img_width),
  batch_size = batch_size)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=42,
    label_mode = 'categorical',
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size)
class_names = trains_ds.class_names
print(class_names)
resnet_model = Sequential()
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                                                  input_shape=(100,100,3),
                                                  pooling='avg', 
                                                  classes = 2204, 
                                                  weights = 'imagenet')

for layer in pretrained_model.layers: 
    layer.trainable=False
resnet_model.add(pretrained_model)
resnet_model.add(Flatten())
resnet_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
resnet_model.add(Dense(5,activation='softmax'))
resnet_model.summary()
resnet_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
epochs = 10
history= resnet_model.fit(
    trains_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs)
```

"""
the error is here:

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-6535b9e974a6> in <module>()
      3     trains_ds,
      4     validation_data=val_ds,
----> 5     epochs=epochs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    762     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    763         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 764             *args, **kwds))
    765 
    766     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3048       args, kwargs = None, None
   3049     with self._lock:
-> 3050       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3051     return graph_function
   3052 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3287             arg_names=arg_names,
   3288             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3289             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3290         self._function_attributes,
   3291         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:845 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:838 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:797 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:155 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:259 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1644 categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4862 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 2204) and (None, 5) are incompatible
```

Comment: Your last dense layer dimension should match the number of classes.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, there are 2204 classes in your dataset, you need to mention the number of classes = 2204 in the last layer of model definition to fix this error. (as suggested by @3nws)

For this, you need to replace this line of code

```
resnet_model.add(Dense(5,activation='softmax'))
```

with

```
resnet_model.add(Dense(2204,activation='softmax'))
```